# Close BufferedOutputStream output after 30 seconds if download fails

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, streamwriter

On clicking Download, my code starts writing content from SAN location in a new opened tab window and once complete, downloads PDF to local system. I would like to close the new tab window if the file does not get writes/downloaded atmost in 30 seconds. and then display a text message on the parent window JSP. My servlet code as below:

```
    try
    {   
        GetPDAO getPDAO= new GetPDAO();

          for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
          {
              content=getPDAO.getPFromE( strPN);
               DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss");
               Date dateobj = new Date();
               if(content==null) 
              {  
               Thread.sleep(5000);
               }
             else {

                 content=getPDAO.getPFromE( strPN);
                 break;
             }
          }
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        String strFileName=strPN+".pdf";
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + strFileName + "\"");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); 
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store"); 
        response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
        output =new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
        output.write(content); 
        output.flush();          
        } 
    finally 
     {
        output.close(); 
      }
```

and my JSP code as below:

```
function onSubmit()
{    
var url="<%=strCCPURL%>"+"/getpfromeservlet?PN="+document.getElementById("pn").value; 
       document.getElementById('alrt').innerHTML='<b>Please wait</b>'; 
           setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById('alrt').innerHTML='';},8000);
            window.open(url,"_blank");
           document.getElementById('viewPD').href=url;
           document.getElementById('viewPD').target='_blank';            
}
```

Comment: And the question is? NB If you want a 30-second timeout why are you setting an 8-second timeout?

Comment: Some r misusing downvote here. If u see, 8 secs is for different" please wait" alert that is shown for the timen then hides(setTimeOut).Q is how will the new opened tab autoclose after 30 secs

Comment: @EJP Can someone help please. I'm totally stuck. My Q is in a servlet with contentType as (application/pdf), can I write anything so that i can use window.close to close my new opened window and Take my focus back to JSP. All i would like to do is show a message after 30 seconds that my download has failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use sendRedirect from your servlet to replica of your JSP and then auto close the JSP. sendRedirect will close the servlet and then replica JSP will get closed via window.close method. Focus is back to your main JSP.